# underscore.js template || bind/append backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I asked question the other day on this app; after some good advice, I moved on and I now think this is a different issue.
Before, I was not getting any display on the screen/no errors or any console.logs. After working on it some more, I now have my model/view and some of my render function working.

I think the issue is with my template or with my append. Below is the full code as it stands now. There are //comments where I think there maybe some issues. 
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT ::** Thanks for the advice Niranjan. I made some the changes you mentioned; I took away the counter and sample data. With these new changes, my newsFeed.js is no longer being read and so I am unclear as to how to populate my collection. When I console.log out my collection I get an empty array with my defaults shown, but with the json file not being read in the first place how do I get anything to work?

**EDIT#2 ::** Thank you again Niranjan. With the changes you suggested and a few of my own, I now have the code below. The issue I have right now, Is my array is being populated far too many times. the JSON file has 8 entries in total and because of my _.each statement in my template it is looping 8 times where I only want it to loop once and then to split the array into separate entries. I tried first splitting it during my response parse but this didn't work, do you have any advice for this?

*below the code is links to the live views of code and html/broswer content including a link to the JSON file.*

My end goal is to click on one title and have the corresponding content show.

```
        (function(){        

    var NewsFeedModel  = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        }
    });

    var NewsFeedCollection  = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: NewsFeedModel,
        url : 'newsFeed.js',
            parse: function(response) {
                console.log('collection and file loaded');
             return response.responseData.feed.entries;
            }
    });

    var NewsFeedView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : '.newsContainer ul',
        template: _.template($("#feedTemp").html()),  
        initialize: function(){ 
         var scopeThis = this;
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

                this.collection.fetch({
                    success: function(collection){
                        scopeThis.render();
                    }
                });

                this.collection.bind( 'add',  this.render, this);
                console.log('View and Template read');
    },  
    render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template({
            feed: this.collection.toJSON() 
      }));
      console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    }

});

 var newsFeedCollection = new NewsFeedCollection();


    var newsFeedView = new NewsFeedView({
    collection: newsFeedCollection
});

var title = newsFeedCollection.find('title');
var content = newsFeedCollection.find('content > title'); 

$(document).on("click", "#add", function(title, content) { 
    console.log("I have been clicked"); 

    if($(title) == $(content)){
    console.log('they match');
    }
    else{
    console.log('they dont match');
    }
$('.hide').slideToggle("slow");


});


}());
```

This is my underscore template.

```
   <div class="span12">
<script id="feedTemp" type="text/template">
    <% _.each(feed, function(data) { %> 
       <div id = "titleContent"> 
         <a href='#' id ="add"> <%= data.title %> </a>
             <div id="content" class="hide">
                <%= data.content %>
             </div> 
       </div>
<% }); %>
</script>           
</div>
```

I am using google drive as a testing ground; links for the full html/code.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0mP2FImEQ6qa3hFTG1YUXpQQm8/edit [code View]
https://googledrive.com/host/0B0mP2FImEQ6qUnFrU3lGcEplb2s/feed.html [browser View]
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0mP2FImEQ6qbnBtYnVTWnpheGM/edit [JSON file]

Answer (score 0):

There are lot more things in your code that can be improved.
Here is the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/d78Kt/2/)**.

Please go through the comments mentioned in the code.

For trying out things in Underscore's template, check [Underscore's Template Editor](http://niranjan-borawake.github.io/ute/).

**Template:**

```
<button id=add>Add</button>
<div class="newsConatiner">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<script id="feedTemp">
    <% _.each(feed, function(data) { %> 
        <div id = "titleContent"> 
            <h2> <%= data.title %> </h2>
            <div id="content">
                <%= data.content %>
            </div> 
        </div>
   <% }); %>
</script>
```

**Code:**

```
(function () {

    var NewsFeedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        //url: 'newsFeed.js',
        defaults: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        }
    });

    var NewsFeedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: NewsFeedModel,
        url: 'newsFeed.js',
        parse: function (response) {
            console.log('collection  and file loaded');
            return response.responseData.feed.entries;
        }
    });

    var NewsFeedView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.newsConatiner',
        //template should not be inside initialize
        template: _.template($("#feedTemp").html()),
        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.render();

            //ADD event on collection
            this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this);
            console.log('View and Template read');
        },
        /*
        This initialize will fetch collection data from newsFeed.js.
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            this.collection.fetch({
                success: function(collection){
                    self.render();
                }
            });
            //ADD event on collection
            this.collection.bind('add', this.render, this);
            console.log('View and Template read');
        },

         */
        render: function () {
            //This is how you can render
            //Checkout how this.collection is used
            this.$el.html(this.template({
                feed: this.collection.toJSON()
            }));
        }
    });
    //Initialized collection with sample data
    var newsCounter = 0;
    var newsFeedCollection = new NewsFeedCollection([{
        title: 'News '+newsCounter++,
        content: 'Content'
    }]);

    //Created view instance and passed collection
    //which is then used in render as this.collection
    var newsFeedView = new NewsFeedView({
        collection: newsFeedCollection
    });
    $('#add').click(function(){
        newsFeedCollection.add(new NewsFeedModel({
            title: 'News ' + newsCounter++,
            content: 'Content'
        }));
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) Please could you have a look over the edits I made from your suggestions? My file is no longer being read and I have no data to initialize my collection.. Thanks

Comment: @LadyRhaebosis You are welcome. I have updated the code and added a modified `initialize` method which should fetch data from `newsFeed.js`.

Comment: Thank you again for your advice. Please could you look over the code once more. My _.each loop is going crazy. Thank you for this, it's really appreciated :)